# Defining methods in a loop from an array of method names

Tags: javascript

I want to define several methods from an array of method names like so:

```
var methodNames = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    randomObject = {}, method;

for( var i = methodNames.length - 1; i >= 0; --i ){
  method = methodNames[ i ];

  randomObject[ method ] = function(){
    console.log( method );
  }
}
```

So that I end up with an object `randomObject`, which has all the methods defined doing the exact same thing. The problem is, every method logs 'foo' instead of the name of the method being called. How can I make the variable `method` persist when the method is called?

Comment: I wish I could tell you the answer, but I bet the answer will involve a "closure".

Comment: I wonder what the record is for the number of times this question has been asked in a 24 hour period.

Comment: @user1689607 i know, i know, just got lazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell if this is the **best** way to use a closure, but I think this is working...

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDrCK/1/

```
var methodNames = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    randomObject = {},
    method;

for (var i = methodNames.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    method = methodNames[i];

    randomObject[method] = (function(met){
        return function () {
            console.log(met);
        }
    })(method);
}

randomObject.baz();
randomObject.bar();
randomObject.foo();
```

Comment: Crap, re-read and see that each function shouldn't be called immediately...

Comment: It's not about using a **closure**, it's about creating a new scope by executing a function. OP is already using a closure.

Comment: @FelixKling True, but isn't executing a function considered a closure? I know it's just terminology, but still

Comment: Not really. A closure is a function that has access to variables defined in a higher/outside scope (that's actually all of it). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap it in a self-executing closure:

```
for (var i = methodNames.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    (function(method) {
        randomObject[method] = function() {
            console.log(method);
        };
    })(methodNames[i]);
}​
```